# Make a USB boot drive for a Mac using a PC

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, macbook

So I have a non-functioning Mac. I have erased its HDD now and will reinstall the HDD back into the MacBook Pro (Late 2011 with an i5 processor). But because I can not install the Mac OS if I want to create the USB for the MacBook to boot from I need to do this in a PC.

The question is: How do I make a bootable USB drive from a PC so a MacBook with no OS on it can boot up with Ubuntu. My plan is to have Ubuntu as the only OS on the system completely.

Comment: I can try... I did this (when I had access to a mac) and it didn't work: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0 so I am not sure whether or not this way will work either. But, is it possible to make a USB drive bootable from a PC to a Mac?

Comment: I think you will have better luck if you try to do this with Ubuntu instead of Windows. It will be tricky formatting the USB unless you have a chance of luck with rufus or some CLI commands. The issue with Windows (I believe) is that once the drive is formatted for your mac, you'll no longer be able to really work on it ( the drive/ filesystem ) in the windows environment. Where as in the Linux environment you should have more access. Someone, anyone, please correct me, or add-to if I'm incorrect.

Comment: I tried two ways now and both ways have lead to the same end point of nothing.

Comment: The first was was using a Macbook to create the drive following the previously mentioned tutorial and the outcome was this: https://photos.app.goo.gl/o6FJkX1Z3TZKto5i6

The second time I tried I made the USB drive with Rufus on a PC and this is the outcome: https://photos.app.goo.gl/bFH15wnAep79fotJA

As well as the same end point: https://photos.app.goo.gl/ktWQVvG5UrJsKLKn8